# I want to search name from database using edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText Search_By_Name;
    private ArrayList<Personal_loan> array;
    private ArrayAdapter<Personal_loan> adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor ;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    Personal_loan p = new Personal_loan();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Search_By_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchName);
        array = new ArrayList<Personal_loan>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Personal_loan>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        getData();
    }
    private void getData() {
        DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String columns[] = new String[] {ID,Name,START_DATE,END_DATE,LOAN_AMOUNT,RATE_OF_INTEREST,FINAL_AMOUNT};
        cursor = db.query( false, LOAN_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                p = new Personal_loan();
                p.id = cursor.getInt(0);
                p.name = cursor.getString(1);
                p.sd = cursor.getString(2);
                p.ed = cursor.getString(3);
                p.la = cursor.getDouble(4);
                p.roi = cursor.getFloat(5);
                p.amt=cursor.getString(6);
                array.add(p);
                cursor.moveToNext();
                Search_By_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    } 
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        s=Search_By_Name.getText();
                        p.name=s.toString();
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is my updated code, it filtered the data but using the last field, not by name field... it took the last field for filtering, if any know the answer plz do share

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: Application need a event to get EditText value enter by user . so when retrieving value from EditText on Button click?

Comment: where you are reading edittext value?

Comment: how can u explain it?

Comment: ... or in `onTextChanged()`

Comment: i used TextWatcher also , it didnot work

Comment: Priyanka, you only call `getData()` in the Activity creation, when the EditText is **empty**. You should implement a Button or the `onTextChanged()` method of your EditText, to search its contents in the `getData()` method when it is not empty. By the way, you should pass the searched string as a parameter and use the WHERE condition to search that in the db. And not rely on absolute column positions.

Comment: `I used TextWatcher in getData()` makes **no sense**, to me. Do you mean `I used getData() in TextWatcher`?

Comment: "Select * from LOAN_TABLE where Name Like Search_By_Name.getText().toString()" i used this query for searching name from database

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
  Search_By_Name .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { 
          // TODO  Auto-generated method stub 
         String text =  search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()); //
          Your_Activity.this.adapter.filter(text); }

          @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int
          arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { 
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
          int arg2, int arg3) { 
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           } });
```

Reference [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)